# Two questions in C++ language

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning C++ language.  There are two concepts I can not figure out:

1. What is the difference between new and malloc?
2. What is the difference between pointer and reference?

Can anyone help?

---

*The original title of the question and the claim about learning said the question was about C, not C++.  But the questions are clearly about C++, not C, because one of the two items in each question does not exist as a relevant concept in C.*

Comment: Uhm... I don't think `new` exists in C ;) Are you talking about C# or C++?

Comment: The difference is that `new` and references don't exist in C, so you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: @larsman: And worrying is what they cause :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C is not C++.

`new` is how you allocate memory *and* call constructors in C++. `malloc` just allocates memory, in both C and C++.

A pointer can be NULL - aka point to a defined invalid location. A reference (which doesn't exist in C) will always refer to something - it cannot legally refer to an invalid location.

Comment: Also, references are not resettable, once you create them they are an *alias* to the original object and all further operations apply to that object, while pointers have entity of their own.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're asking about C++, not just C.

1. `malloc()` is the most common memory allocation function; it allocates at least as many bytes that the user requests. `new` is exclusive to C++ and is an operator rather than a function call; it invokes a class's constructor after allocating the memory.
2. A *pointer* is a variable that stores a memory address. A *reference* is exclusive to C++; it is an abstraction that essentially looks like variable has been renamed.

Answer (score 0):

A reference allows you to pass the actual variable not a copy of it to a function so it can be modified without the possible problems pointers can incur.